# How to match and store results from a long nested for loop into an empty column in a data frame in R

Tags: r, loops, dataframe, p-value

I'm trying to store p values from a long nested for loop into an empty column in a data frame. I've tried looking up examples close to my code, but I feel as though my code is really long (and maybe even incorrect) that the same things that can be applied to other for loops can't be applied to mine.

The overview of what I'm trying to do is I'm trying to compare the relatedness of observed paired birds to the relatedness of all possible paired birds in a given year by finding a p value. To do this, I'm writing a for loop where I am selecting a range of years from a huge data set, and then I am applying a bunch of functions to those given years where I'm trying to narrow down the data for observed pairs and then I'm adding a column for relatedness and transferring those relatedness values for the pairs from another data set. I am then applying another for loop function within this in order to create a data frame with all possible paired birds in that given year and also adding and transferring a column of relatedness values for the pairs. From these two data frames of pairs and relatedness within each year, I want to apply the wilcox test to find the p value for each given year. I want to transfer over these p values into a separate data frame that I have created with a year column and a p value column.

Here is my (crazy looking) code:

```
`year <- c(2000:2013)
 pvalue <- c(NA)
 results <- data.frame(year, pvalue)
 for(j in c(2000:2013)) {
  allbr_demo_noEPP_year <- subset(allbr_demo_noEPP, Year == j)
  allbr_demo_noEPP_year_geno_obs <-  allbr_demo_noEPP_year[allbr_demo_noEPP_year$Pairs %in% c(genome$pair1,genome$pair2),]
  allbr_demo_noEPP_year_geno_obs$relatedness <- laply(allbr_demo_noEPP_year_geno_obs$Pairs, function(x) genome[genome$pair1==x|genome$pair2==x,'PI_HAT'])
  allbr_demo_noEPP_year_geno <- allbr_demo_noEPP_year[c(allbr_demo_noEPP_year$MB_USFWS,allbr_demo_noEPP_year$FB_USFWS) %in% genotyped$V2,]
  breeder_list_males <- allbr_demo_noEPP_year_geno_obs[,8]
  breeder_list_females <- allbr_demo_noEPP_year_geno_obs[,10]
  unq_breeder_list_males <- unique(breeder_list_males)
  unq_breeder_list_females <- unique(breeder_list_females)
  all_poss_combo <-list()
  for(i in unq_breeder_list_males){
   print(i)
   all_poss_combo[[i]]<-paste0(i, ",", unq_breeder_list_females)}
   lapply(X = all_poss_combo, FUN= function(x) length(unique(x)))
   all_poss_df<-unlist(all_poss_combo, use.names = F)
   all_poss_df <- data.frame("combo"=all_poss_df, "M"=NA, "F"=NA)
   all_poss_df$M <- substr(all_poss_df$combo, start = 1, stop = 10)
   all_poss_df$F <- substr(all_poss_df$combo, start = 12, stop = 22)
   all_poss_df_geno <- all_poss_df[all_poss_df$combo %in% c(genome$pair1,genome$pair2),]
   all_poss_df_geno$relatedness <- laply(all_poss_df_geno$combo, function(x) genome[genome$pair1==x|genome$pair2==x,'PI_HAT'])
   wilcox.test(allbr_demo_noEPP_year_geno_obs$relatedness, all_poss_df_geno$relatedness, alternative='greater')}`
```

To be honest, I'm not even sure if this for loop will work (it seems pretty complex to me, but I am a beginner), but I was told that doing a for loop for this situation should work. I understand there are probably easier or faster ways to do what I am trying to do, which I also welcome, but I would also like to see how I could fix this for loop so it would work and how I could store the results from it into a data frame.

Thank you so much for any help given!

Comment: Would you mind posting a portion of your dataset so one might be able to run your code? using dput on a subset of your data would give you output that you can edit into your original question. Perhaps dput(allbr_demo_noEPP[1:30,]) ?

Comment: Hi Evan, I'm not sure if I should because the data is not mine. I'm working with someone else's research data, so it isn't mine to decide to share publicly. Thank you for trying to help though! Maybe I should remove my question because it might be too difficult to help without the data set.

Comment: Yes, we typically don't recommend sharing private research data - we usually recommend creating a sample from scratch with an expected output. However, I took a look and let me know if you wanted something more-- because it seemed to me you just wanted to capture the pvalue in a dataframe from your for loop results?

Comment: Difficult to answer without some kind of data. However, in general it is better to manipulate data frames using packages that provide functions to reshape and tidy data *e.g* `dplyr`, `tidyr`, than to use complicated loops.

Comment: @Evan Friedland, yes I wanted to capture the pvalues to see if I got any outputs that made any sense. I tried what you suggested except I put results[j] instead of pvalue[j] because I thought that it was supposed to be the same of the dataframe, but it returned an error saying "Error in `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, , j, value = NULL) : 
  new columns would leave holes after existing columns" So there must be something wrong with my loop function.

Comment: Right, so results is a dataframe. results[rows,columns] is the subsetting format. What you want then is results[j,2], in other words, your second column to be filled, one row at a time.

Comment: I tried that, and it gives me this error: "Error in x[[jj]][iseq] <- vjj : replacement has length zero"

Answer (score 1):

If you are simply looking to save the p value:

```
str(wilcox.test(rnorm(10), rnorm(10, 2))) # example from running ?Wilcox.test
wilcox.test(rnorm(10), rnorm(10, 2))$p.value #
```

So with your dataset, perhaps putting this in the bottom of your for loop:

```
pvalue[j] <- wilcox.test(allbr_demo_noEPP_year_geno_obs$relatedness, 
                         all_poss_df_geno$relatedness, alternative='greater')$p.value
```